# Jquery .click() function Implementation on a class Issue

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to implement a simple code in Jquery where if I click on any element of of class I must get a pop-up saying **hello**.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumb_radio").click(function(){

       alert("hello");


    });

});
```

But This doesn't work.

HTML is like this:

```
<tr>
<td>
<input id="thumb_radio_0" class="thumb_radio" type="radio" value="0" name="thumbnail_template">
Please select ...
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="thumb_radio_1" class="thumb_radio" type="radio" value="1" name="thumbnail_template">
one

</td>
<td>
<input id="thumb_radio_2" class="thumb_radio" type="radio" value="2" name="thumbnail_template">
two

</td>
<td>
<input id="thumb_radio_3" class="thumb_radio" type="radio" value="3" name="thumbnail_template">
three

</td>
<td>
<input id="thumb_radio_4" class="thumb_radio" type="radio" value="4" name="thumbnail_template">
four

</td>
</tr>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you binding after the elements are rendered or wrapping the binding call in `document.ready`?

Comment: 1 of two things, either A) You need to use a `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code })` wrapper, or B) your jQuery library isn't included. i can't tell.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy ya `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code })` is already their. and JQuery Library is included too.

Comment: any error you see in console?]

Comment: It does show an error but its totally Unrelated. but anyways here it is: `TypeError: document.body.getElementsByTagName is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var children = ($(parentElement) || document.body).getElementsByTagName('*');' in file `prototype.js (line 886)` which is totally Unrelated.

Comment: are you including any other  libraries, after jquery?

Comment: @HussainNagri....Check this out in fiddler. http://jsfiddle.net/UtcQu/

Comment: the fiddle link that you have given is working fine can you please show your page code what libraries you are using and html code also

Comment: Guyz I added `jQuery.noConflict()` the Prototype Error is gone but the function still don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype also overrides the `$` variable.  If you want to use jQuery with it, you have to remove the conflict.  jQuery has a method to do this on its own: [`$.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: I added `jQuery.noConflict()` the Prototype Error is gone but the function still don't work.

Comment: You also have to change your code to use `jQuery(".thumb_radio").click` or use `$(document).ready(function ($) {`.  Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".thumb_radio").click(function(){
       alert("hello");
    });
 });

</script>
```

Fiddler Example : http://jsfiddle.net/UtcQu/

Exact Source : view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/UtcQu/show/light/

May be you need to do something like `jQuery.noConflict()` if you using any other libraries along with native jquery.

Comment: I added jQuery.noConflict() the Prototype Error is gone but the function still don't work.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".thumb_radio").click(function(){
       alert("hello");
    });

});
```